# Model a date time range object hierarchy

Tags: c#, refactoring, solid-principles

Newbie to code refactoring, I have a simple object as follow

```
public class TimeRange
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    }

    public class ActTimeRange : TimeRange
    {

    }

    public class PlannedTimeRange : TimeRange
    {

    }
```

I am thinking should if I should shrink this class hierarchy relationship by cutting down the two children classes and instead replace them with a boolean property on the parent class (i.e IsPlanned), which one would be better performance wise?

Comment: Using OOP and a hierarchy you should not need to use a bool such as IsPlanned because the type PlannedTimeRange tells that it is planned. What are these two others classes ? Do they need to inherits from TimeRange ? What are all the properties that need to have all these classes if you don't think in terms of inheritence ? Can you put the code, or a sketch, in the question, please ? What does these classes ? What's the goal ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier - He's asking if he should drop the two child classes and only use the parent class, but with an `IsPlanned` property. That's his question essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't seem to be adding any other properties to `ActTimeRange` and `PlannedTimeRange` it might be better to do this kind of model:

```
public class TimeRange
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public TimeRangeStatus Status { get; set; } = TimeRangeStatus.None;
}

public enum TimeRangeStatus
{
    None,
    Actual,
    Planned
}
```

I would avoid `bool` as a property or field as you can end up with method calls like `DoSomething(true, false)` - which are not very clear. It's better to have `DoSomething(TimeRangeStatus.Actual, SomeOtherFlag.Red)`.

Performance should not be a concern with any approach.